# What is precedence order in relaxng compact notation?

Tags: xml, xsd, relaxng, relaxng-compact

What is the order of precedence of the `*`, `?`, `|` and `,` operators in relaxng compact notation?

For example:

```
start = element A { B | C , D * }
```

Which of these, is the above equivalent to?

```
start = element A { (( B | C ) , D) * }
start = element A { (B | (C , D)) * }
start = element A { (B | C) , (D *) }
start = element A { B | (C , (D *)) }
```

Where is this documented?

Comment: See https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/relax-ng/compact-20021121.html#syntax *“There is no notion of operator precedence. It is an error for patterns to combine the `|`, `&`, `,` and `-` operators without using parentheses to make the grouping explicit. For example, `foo | bar, baz` is not allowed; instead, either `(foo | bar), baz` or `foo | (bar, baz)` must be used.”*